# Notação matemática no SOPT

Tags: novo-recurso

Existe como utilizar notação matemática nas perguntas, respostas e comentários do SOPT, talvez nos mesmos moldes do que é feito [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com) ou no [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) do grupo StackExchange?

Answer (score 21):

Fui procurar no SO pra ver como funcionava e descobri que (ao menos por lá) não existe tal recurso e provavelmente nunca existirá.

Os sites Math e Physics utilizam uma ferramenta chamada [MathJax que é baseada na sintaxe de formatação do Latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Já houve [uma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation) ou [outra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow/60020) solicitação para que esse recurso fosse ativado no SO, mas o consenso geral é de que se trata de [um recurso computacionalmente custoso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203977/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on/204003#204003) e por isso inapropriado para o escopo do site (em que equações matemáticas são raramente utilizadas).

Eu acho que os argumentos da diminuição da velocidade de renderização das páginas e do pouco uso de equações matemáticas do SO são válidos aqui também, assim como a discussão é igualmente justa. De todas as formas, estou postando essa resposta para oferecer duas soluções alternativas que eu encontrei, pois o fato é que em computação equações matemáticas são eventualmente necessárias (eu mesmo já tive uma ou outra necessidade por aqui - acabei reutilizando imagens da Wikipedia na época).

A primeira solução que eu encontrei foi utilizada [nesse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977792/matlab-equation) do SO sobre Matlab. O OP empregou marcações html e símbolos textuais para construir sua equação:

```
y<sub>t</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>p</sup>  (a<sub>i</sub> ⋅ y<sub>t-i</sub>), t ≥ p
```

Resultando em:

> y<sub>t</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>p</sup>  (a<sub>i</sub> ⋅ y<sub>t-i</sub>), t ≥ p

Apesar de ser simples e fácil de ser editado, essa abordagem é bastante limitada em relação ao que se pode representar da notação matemática.

Uma segunda solução tem origem nas discussões do Metão sobre o recurso, em que foram indicados diversos sites em que se pode utilizar a notação matemática do Latex para renderizar online as equações. Essa abordagem funciona perfeitamente para perguntas e respostas, mas não para comentários (pois, até onde eu sei, não é possível incluir imagens nos comentários).

Um exemplo de ferramenta online que faz a renderização de equações é o [Latex Equation Editor](http://pt.numberempire.com/texequationeditor/equationeditor.php). Para ilustrar, eu utilizei a ferramenta para reproduzir [a equação complexa do Filtro de Gabor da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter):

```latex
g \left( x,y;\lambda,\theta,\psi,\sigma,\gamma \right) = \exp \left( -\frac{{x^'}^2+\gamma^2{y^'}^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \exp \left( i \left( 2\pi\frac{x^'}{\lambda}+\psi \right) \right)
```

É simples assim: acesse a ferramenta, digite o código em Latex e clique no botão "Render Equation"; a equação será renderizada em uma imagem (no caso dessa ferramenta, no formato GIF) que pode ser simplesmente baixada e inserida no post da pergunta ou da resposta.

**Utilizando a ferramenta:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Incluindo a equação no post:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa abordagem também simples e especialmente bacana pra quem já conhece Latex. Porém, dificulta eventuais correções necessárias na equação (pois o que se tem no post é apenas a imagem). Por isso, se você utilizar essa solução, talvez seja uma boa prática "armazenar" no post o código Latex original da equação (e talvez o link para a ferramenta online que utilizou para renderizá-la). Isso pode ser feito utilizando as tags de comentário html, como por exemplo:

```html
<!--
Este texto está comentado para ilustrar que pode ser uma boa prática "armazenar" no
post da pergunta ou da resposta o código Latex utilizado para gerar a imagem.

Latex da equação: g \left( x,y;\lambda,\theta,\psi,\sigma,\gamma \right) = \exp 
\left( -\frac{{x^'}^2+\gamma^2{y^'}^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \exp \left( i \left( 
2\pi\frac{x^'}{\lambda}+\psi \right) \right)

Ferramenta de renderização:    
http://pt.numberempire.com/texequationeditor/equationeditor.php
-->
```

No caso da ferramenta que eu sugeri, também é possível referenciar diretamente a URL da ferramenta provendo o código Latex como parâmetros:

```
http://latex.numberempire.com/render?g%20\left(%20x,y;\lambda,\theta,\psi,\sigma,\gamma%20\right)%20=%20\exp%20\left(%20-\frac{{x^%27}^2+\gamma^2{y^%27}^2}{2\sigma^2}%20\right)%20\exp%20\left(%20i%20\left(%202\pi\frac{x^%27}{\lambda}+\psi%20\right)%20\right)
```

Fica bem mais fácil de manter, mas o post torna-se dependente do site da ferramenta estar online.

**Equações do Google Charts**

Há outra opção bastante interessante que utiliza os recursos do [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas) para renderização das equações. Esse recurso online também utiliza a sintaxe do Tex. Por exemplo, a equação a seguir está sendo renderizada diretamente da Web por meio desse serviço online:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para incluí-la na postagem, basta adicionar uma imagem e indicar o link da seguinte forma:

- Utilize `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?` como raíz
- e adicione os parâmetros `cht=tx` (para indicar que a renderização é de uma imagem) e `chl=<dados da equação>` com os dados da equação na sintaxe do Latex/Tex

Note que a fórmula precisa ser codificada para ser uma URL válida - no exemplo acima, o sinal de `+` precisa ser codificado como `%2B`, resultando na seguinte URL para a imagem na postagem:

> [https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=a^2%2Bb^2=c^2](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=a%5E2%2bb%5E2=c%5E2)

Mesmo sendo um serviço online, eu creio que por ser do Google pode-se considerá-lo de confiança. De todas as formas, recentemente eu percebi que aparentemente o StackExchange faz um upload de uma cópia da imagem quando ela é inserida por meio de uma URL (pois ele até falha se o formato da imagem não for reconhecido), e por isso mesmo que o serviço saia do ar isso pode não ser mais um problema.