# Opção de criar tabela no editor de texto não seria interessante?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto

Não seria interessante a disponibilização de uma tabela no editor de textos?

Principalmente para representação de `matrizes` e `tabelas` de `banco de dados`?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5715/14262

Comment: Olá Felipe, sei que faz tempo, mas faltou comunicar aqui no site (acabei fazendo no Sandbox na época e não me atentei a postagem correta, que é a sua), então agora editei a publicação explicando como usar o markdown especifico para tabelas: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5716/3635

Answer (score 16):

Sim, seria. [Já foi pedido antes e foi declinado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/140010).

Não é fácil implementar certo, as pessoas nem sempre usam certo e não fica bom em todas situações, então se optou por não fazer. Uma pena. Pode ser útil.

O jeito é fazer na mão ou criar uma imagem com a tabela, [como eu costumo fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13388/101).

Comment: Podia ser mais um recurso liberado com pontos, assim como snippet (que devia ser um pouco mais "caro" pra liberar na minha humilde opinião), assim seria usado só à medida que as pessoas forem ganhando experiência com o básico.

Comment: @Bacco realamente eu acho que tem vários recursos que podiam liberar, principalmente para os usuários mais avançados, inclusive acho que precisa ter mais escalas para incentivar o pessoa participar, muita gente para no 10K, no 20K pq a gamificação diminui.

Comment: Pouparia um grande esforço, como você bem falou criando imagens com tabelas e fazendo upload dela, realmente uma pena =/

Comment: Tabelas como imagem são algo ruim, imho, simplesmente porque o texto não pode ser facilmente copiado. É uma pena que esse recurso não exista. :/

Comment: @LuizVieira concordo.

Comment: Também tem o fato de que o texto em imagem não é indexado pelos motores de busca... Aliás, será que hoje em dia não vale a pena tentar _pedir_ a implementação das tabelas novamente?

Answer (score 13):

Desde [Novembro de 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) a sintaxe de tabelas são suportadas nos sites da rede, segue os exemplos de markdown

Código fonte:

```
foo | bar | baz
----|-----|-----
1   | 2   | 3
1   | 2   | 3
1   | 2   | 3
```

Resultado:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Não é necessário o alinhamento dos PIPES (`|`), só adicionei para facilitar a leitura, **sem espaçamentos**, código fonte:

```
foo|bar|baz
---|---|---
1|2|3
1|2|3
1|2|3
1|2|3
```

Resultado:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Também não é necessário adicionar PIPES no começo e fim, apesar de não afetar a estrutura, exemplo:

```
| foo | bar | baz |
|-----|-----|-----|
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
```

Resultado:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

## Alinhar texto das células na tabela

Ele suporta alinhamento de texto, usando:

- `---:` alinhar a direita
- `:---` alinhar a esquerda (por padrão TH e TD estão como left, então isso é dispensável)
- `:---:` alinhar no centro

Exemplo, código fonte:

```
direita | centro | esquerda | padrão
-------:|:------:|:---------|-------
1       | 2      | 3        | 4
1       | 2      | 3        | 4
1       | 2      | 3        | 4
```

Resultado:

| direita | centro | esquerda | padrão |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

---

Para testes de melhorias/funcionamentos use o sandbox especifico (edições são comunitárias, mas lá você pode criar novos testes com o campo de "Sua resposta"):

- [Sandbox tabelas reais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8525/3635)

As tabelas são disponíveis apenas no Documentation (descontinuado), talvez seja questão de tempo até existir nos demais *Stack Overflows* e sites da *rede*, mas não tem mesmo no SOen, acho que vai demorar de adicionarem (ou nem irão adicionar).

Por enquanto alguns exemplos provisórios [importados do Metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139013/198279):

```
+------------+---------+
|    Type    |  MySQL  |
+------------+---------+
| Header     | Top Row |
| Auto Align | On      |
+------------+---------+
```

```
+------------+---------+
| Type       | MySQL   |
| Header     | None    |
| Auto Align | On      |
+------------+---------+
```

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |     A      |      B      |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | Type       | MySQL       |
| 2 | Header     | Spreadsheet |
| 3 | Auto Align | On          |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ A          ║ B           ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Type       ║ Unicode Art ║
║ 2 ║ Header     ║ Spreadsheet ║
║ 3 ║ Auto Align ║ Off         ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Bordas arredondadas com unicode não tem como acertar muito:

```
╭───╥────────────┬─────────────╮
│   ║     1      │     2       │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A ║ Type       │ Manual      │
│ B ║ Header     │ Anything    │
│ C ║      Align │        Sure │
└───╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Uma versão mesclada:

```
┌───╥────────────┬─────────────┐
│   ║     1      │     2       │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A ║ Type       │ Manual      │
│ B ║ Header     │ Anything    │
│ C ║      Align │        Sure │
└───╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Só escolher a que mais lhe agrada.

Comment: Boa sugestão, não sei por que mas me lembrou do primeiro ano de faculdade e visualg :')

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Eu já usei o 1 e o 2, só esse com bordas arredondadas não, prefiro o um. Na verdade o bigown tinha linkado, mas eu prefiro copiar pra cá para evitar os cliques :D

Comment: Vi agora que ele tinha linkado kkk, de manhã a belíssima internet daqui não deu conta de carregar a página, mas é melhor deixar nessa página também ^^

Answer (score 9):

Eu concordo [com o @bigown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5714/73) de que sim, seria muito útil, mas infelizmente o recurso não existe. Eu acho que é muito ruim a ideia de usar imagens para representar tabelas porque:

1. não dá pra copiar o texto delas facilmente.
2. a manutenção da postagem se torna terrivelmente comprometida; só o(a) autor(a) consegue alterar se precisar, isso se ele(a) guardar a fonte original da imagem.

Sendo assim, me parece muito melhor usar uma alternativa como as propostas pelo [colega @GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5716/73). Eu poderia ter comentado isso, mas resolvi postar uma resposta pra sugerir algumas alternativas adicionais.

### Alternativa 1: Usar recursos do Próprio SOPT

Além das ideias propostas pelo colega Guilherme (e eu acho que o [AscII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) é fantástico!), lá no Metão também tem uma sugestão bacana usando a [formatação de teclas de atalho](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128302/249626) (tag `<kbd/>`) com o conteúdo delimitado pela tag `<code/>` de forma a conseguir controlar a largura das colunas:

<kbd>**`Nome`**</kbd>             <kbd>**`Nota 1`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Nota 2`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Média Final`**</kbd>
<kbd>`Fulano de Tal`</kbd>       <kbd>`7,80`</kbd>   <kbd>`3,60`</kbd>       <kbd>`5,70`</kbd>
<kbd>`Beltrano da Silva`</kbd>   <kbd>`9,00`</kbd>   <kbd>`7,50`</kbd>       <kbd>`8,25`</kbd>
<kbd>`Cicrano do Lago`</kbd>     <kbd>`0,00`</kbd>  <kbd>`10,00`</kbd>       <kbd>`5,00`</kbd>

Essa tabela é produzida com o seguinte código:

```
<kbd>**<code>Nome             </code>**</kbd><kbd>**<code>Nota 1 </code>**</kbd><kbd>**<code>Nota 2 </code>**</kbd><kbd>**<code>Média Final</code>**</kbd><br/>
<kbd><code>Fulano de Tal    </code></kbd><kbd><code>   7,80</code></kbd><kbd><code>   3,60</code></kbd><kbd><code>       5,70</code></kbd><br/>
<kbd><code>Beltrano da Silva</code></kbd><kbd><code>   9,00</code></kbd><kbd><code>   7,50</code></kbd><kbd><code>       8,25</code></kbd><br/>
<kbd><code>Cicrano do Lago  </code></kbd><kbd><code>   0,00</code></kbd><kbd><code>  10,00</code></kbd><kbd><code>       5,00</code></kbd>
```

Com um pequeno e simples script Python dá pra facilmente processar o mesmo formato usado pela ferramenta [AscII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) (ou qualquer outro, basta trocar o separador na variável `sep` do script) e gerar uma tabela com esse padrão. :)

Exemplo (com um pequeno trecho dos dados do [famoso conjunto de dados de flores de Iris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)):

<kbd>**`Comprimento da Sépala`**</kbd><kbd>**`Largura da Sépala`**</kbd><kbd>**`Comprimento da Pétala`**</kbd><kbd>**`Largura da Pétala`**</kbd>
                  <kbd>`5,1`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,5`</kbd>                  <kbd>`1,4`</kbd>              <kbd>`0,2`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`4,9`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,0`</kbd>                  <kbd>`1,4`</kbd>              <kbd>`0,2`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`4,7`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,2`</kbd>                  <kbd>`1,3`</kbd>              <kbd>`0,2`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`4,6`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,1`</kbd>                  <kbd>`1,5`</kbd>              <kbd>`0,2`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`7,0`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,2`</kbd>                  <kbd>`4,7`</kbd>              <kbd>`1,4`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`6,4`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,2`</kbd>                  <kbd>`4,5`</kbd>              <kbd>`1,5`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`6,9`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,1`</kbd>                  <kbd>`4,9`</kbd>              <kbd>`1,5`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`5,5`</kbd>              <kbd>`2,3`</kbd>                  <kbd>`4,0`</kbd>              <kbd>`1,3`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`6,3`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,3`</kbd>                  <kbd>`6,0`</kbd>              <kbd>`2,5`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`5,8`</kbd>              <kbd>`2,7`</kbd>                  <kbd>`5,1`</kbd>              <kbd>`1,9`</kbd>
                  <kbd>`7,1`</kbd>              <kbd>`3,0`</kbd>                  <kbd>`5,9`</kbd>              <kbd>`2,1`</kbd>

O script pode ser usado [diretamente no Ideone](http://ideone.com/MEyVVk) (basta digitar a tabela no input do stdin), mas aqui está ele completo:

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

sep = '\t' # Separador utilizado (default é tabulação)

# Lê o cabeçalho com os nomes das colunas
header = next(sys.stdin).split(sep)

# Cria um dicionário ordenado com uma lista para cada coluna da tabela
data = OrderedDict()
for h in header:
    data[h.strip()] = []

# Lê os dados das linhas (assumindo mesma ordem e quantidade das colunas
# no cabeçalho)
rows = 0
for l in sys.stdin:
    rows += 1
    line = l.split(sep)
    for i, k in enumerate(data.keys()):
        data[k].append(line[i])

# Encontra os tamanhos ideiais de cada coluna
sizes = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    sizes[k] = max(len(max(v, key=len)), len(k))

# Gera a tabela com os dados
header = ''
for k in data.keys():
    header += '<kbd>**<code>{}</code>**</kbd>'.format(k.center(sizes[k]))
print('{}<br/>'.format(header))

for l in range(rows):
    line = ''
    for k, v in data.items():
        line += '<kbd><code>{}</code></kbd>'.format(v[l].rjust(sizes[k]))
    print('{}<br/>'.format(line))
```

### Alternativa 2: Usar um codificador externo

No caso de matrizes (independentemente do contexto ser computacional ou matemático) ou até mesmo tabelas **curtas**, você pode usar o [LaTeX](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) da mesma forma como faz com equações. O SOPT não tem uma implementação nativa do LaTeX tal como outros sites do StackExchange têm (o [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ou o [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), por exemplo), por motivos óbvios: aqui isso é pouquíssimo usado e torna-se um esforço desnecessário e custoso. Mas [nesta outra postagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/795/73) aqui do Meta eu forneço exemplos de como usar o LaTeX a partir de fontes externas para gerar uma imagem da matriz desejada. Por exemplo, a matriz M, com duas dimensões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É gerada a partir do código (que pode parecer complexo, [mas não é](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajuda:Guia_de_edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o/F%C3%B3rmulas_TeX): as linhas são definidas por `\\` e as colunas por `&`):

```
M = \begin{bmatrix}
7 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 6 & -8 \\ 
3 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 14 & 44 \\ 
8 & -5 & 67 & 2 & 0 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
```

Sim, o resultado ainda é reproduzido aqui como uma imagem, mas você pode manter o código original como um comentário dentro da postagem (se importar diretamente a imagem renderizada pelo [editor de equações](http://pt.numberempire.com/texequationeditor/equationeditor.php) utilizado) ou usar uma URL do [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)<sup>*</sup>.

> <sup>*</sup> Lá na outra pergunta do Meta tem os detalhes, mas
>   basicamente você passa o código da equação diretamente na URL do
>   Google Charts. Você só precisa codificar os caracteres especiais para
>   eles serem usados via URL, o que pode ser facilmente feito (e
>   desfeito) usando o [URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), por exemplo. Edite esta
>   resposta e olhe o link usado para a imagem da matriz acima, e você
>   verá que se trata dessa url diretamente referenciada na postagem:
>
> https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=M%20%3D%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%0A7%20%26%209%20%26%204%20%26%203%20%26%206%20%26%20-8%20%5C%5C%20%0A3%20%26%204%20%26%206%20%26%201%20%26%2014%20%26%2044%20%5C%5C%20%0A8%20%26%20-5%20%26%2067%20%26%202%20%26%200%20%26%207%0A%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D

Para matrizes, tabelas de texto ou de dados mais longas, essa abordagem vai se tornar mais difícil e pouco prática. Aliás, o Google Charts usado diretamente via URL dessa forma está depreciado (mas o Google diz que *não deve* removê-lo). :/ #bummer A nova API do Google Charts tem muitos outros recursos bacanas, incluindo a criação de [tabelas dinâmicas](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), mas não dá pra usar por aqui a não ser que seja incluído em um *snippet* de código (mas como o usuário precisaria clicar em executar para ver a tabela, eu acho que perde todo o sentido).

Eu procurei mas não encontrei um gerador externo, invocável via URL, que produzisse imagens de tabelas codificadas em HTML. Se um dia encontrar um, eu volto aqui e edito a resposta. :)

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/  <-- isso aqui é interessante =)

Comment: Essa saída do google charts é o que estou usando atualmente, eis um exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178432/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa Rapaz.... pra respostas como aquela sua o LaTeX integrado realmente faz falta. rs :)