# Por que não temos notação LaTeX?

Tags: novo-recurso

No site [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help), temos notação LaTeX. [Aqui, não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Poderiam colocar o suporte?

Comment: Não sei se valeria a pena, seria muito pouco usado...

Comment: Sites como estes podem quebrar o galho: http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php, http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor

Comment: [Não mesmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=f%C3%B3rmula+-excel+-%5Bexcel%5D)

Comment: `382 / 67815 ~ 0.006` 0.6% ainda parece pouco.

Comment: Para esclarecer, não sou contra funcionalidades como essa. Porém, me parece que isso é meio pesado, por isso tomaria cuidado antes de implementar aqui. No Mathematics, por exemplo, dá uma piscada no post equanto processa/renderiza o MathJax.

Comment: Eu [tive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on) que procurar pela resposta - *I'm sorry*.

Comment: Como o @bfavaretto disse, o MathJax é desligado por padrão nos sites por questões de desempenho. Nós ligamos sob pedidos das comunidades, quando elas concordam que é algo que elas precisam. Cabe a vocês resolver o debate.

Comment: Fica bem lento, né? Se é que o nosso volume de dados é bem menor. Não me incomoda dois segundos a mais, mas não sei a opinião dos demais.

Comment: Para alguns navegadores, existem [extensões](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-renderer/enfbnhdcmcipeoakalehejknkpbajodp) que fazem este serviço. Equações *inline* podem ser formatadas entre `$`, tal como $ E = mc^2 $. Claro que a visualização depende do usuário possuir a extensão também, mas o bom é que não afeta a leitura daqueles que não possuem. [Exemplo](http://i.imgur.com/GRlMuiP.png).

Comment: Gostei disso. Acho que é legal adicionar como resposta. A sugestão das extensões poderia ficar na ajuda avançada.

Comment: Eu ia gostar de ter LaTeX. Não teria como fazer uma forma de carregar o MathJax apenas se a página realmente precisar? Assim, na maioria das páginas não ia influenciar em nada e nas que usariam ia ajudar muito!

Comment: Só vi a postagem agora. Mas eu também já tive a mesma dúvida/necessidade: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/795/nota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-matem%c3%a1tica-no-sopt

Comment: @LuizVieira Verdade. Só formulei um pouco diferente de você.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Como alternativa, é possível utilizar extensões do próprio navegador, assim os usuários que possuirem a extensão instalada consegue visualizar as equações renderizadas, enquanto os que não possuirem, verão a equação escrita por extenso - de forma legível.

### Google Chrome

Para o Google Chrome, existe a extensão [Tex Renderer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-renderer/enfbnhdcmcipeoakalehejknkpbajodp). Basta acessar o link e clicar em *Usar no Chrome*. Sua utilização é bem simples: uma vez instalada, qualquer conteúdo da página entre os caracteres `$` será interpretado como uma equação matemática com a notação TeX. A extensão se encarregará de analisar a equação e renderizá-la.

Por exemplo:

```
$ E = mc^2 $
```

É renderizado para:

[image: Equação renderizada]

Ou, para equações mais complexas, é possível utilizar a própria notação de equações do TeX:

```
\begin{equation}
  \left(\!
    \begin{array}{c}
      n \\
      r
    \end{array}
  \!\right) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
\end{equation}
```

Que é renderizado para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que esta segunda forma já deixa de ser legível para quem não possui a extensão instalada.

> **Nota**: a extensão funciona bem aqui no SOpt, mas pode prejudicar a visualização em outras páginas, pois qualquer conteúdo entre `$` seria tratado como equação.

Comment: Existiam extensões semelhantes a esta para outros navegadores também, mas ainda não as encontrei. Talvez foram descontinuadas.

Comment: Teste no sandbox: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5956/3635

Comment: Eu acho essas soluções suficientes, tem outras coisas que precisamos muito mais, como tabelas por exemplo. A solução é criar uma imagem que não é o ideal, mas que resolve. Este caso é não deve ser muito mais que 0,1% dos *posts* por isso acho que uma solução *off-site* gerando uma imagem é mais adequada.

Comment: @bigown 0.6% ;)

Answer (score 22):

Outra forma é utilizar sites de terceiros, tal como o [Latex2PNG](http://latex2png.com/) ou o [Tex2PNG](http://frog.isima.fr/bruno/share/tex2png/). Em ambos é possível escrever a equação utilizando a notação do TeX, gerando um PNG com a equação inserida. Esta imagem pode ser subida para o SOpt pelo sistema nativo de imagens.

### latex2png

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, basta clicar com o botão direito sobre a imagem, ir em *Copy image address* para copiar o endereço da imagem. No SOpt, basta clicar em *Inserir imagem* (ou <kbd>CTRL+G</kbd>), entrar em *link da web* e copiar o endereço da imagem.

O resultado do exemplo mostrado no GIF é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A vantagem é que a equação será exibida para todos os usuários igualmente, porém, sendo uma imagem, a equação não é passível de modificações, tendo que gerá-la novamente caso isso seja necessário.

Comment: Muito bom! Creio que a melhor alternativa.

Comment: Estava buscando se existe alguma API para isso que permitisse a criação de uma aplicação que substituísse o texto selecionado pela imagem gerada, mas não achei nada semelhante.

Comment: Com webextensions dá para fazer algo forçado com o latex2png pois podemos manipular certos comportamentos e já inserir na postagem, eu só estou meio sem tempo, mas talvez eu adicione algo no add-on que criei para o uso dos sites SE.

Answer (score 11):

Acho desnecessário em 99,9% dos casos e, quando for necessário, pode-se utilizar uma solução alternativa conforme proposto nas outras respostas, como [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5955/2652).

O Mathematics tem esse suporte pois é praticamente impossível trabalhar com matemática avançada sem o suporte a LaTeX.

Como o foco do SOpt não são equações matemáticas acho desnecessário. Perguntas relacionadas com equações geralmente são feitas dentro do contexto de um algorítimo e daí a necessidade do LaTex é minimizada.

Acredito que seguindo a mesma linha de raciocínio, os sites SOen, SOes, SOjp e SOru não tem suporte a LaTeX.