# Ferramentas para auxiliar na escrita de conteúdo

Tags: debate, formatação, conteúdo

Eu sou formado em ciências de computação. Acaba que minhas respostas eu gosto de me basear muito em conceitos matemáticos e, quando possível e o tempo convém, com desenhos de grafos. Mas às vezes eu não uso da maneira mais adequada as ferramentas que tenha à mão, e às vezes eu não tenho as ferramentas adequadas à mão.

Por exemplo, o @AndersonCarlosWoss [me chamou no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43978395#43978395) pelo meu pouco senso estético ao postar fórmulas em LaTeX:

> [...] se você usa o latex2png para as equações nas suas respostas, recomendaria diminuir a resolução ao gerar o PNG, para a imagem final não ficar tão grande a ponto de não se encaixar no texto
>
> [...]
>
> Resolução de 150

Logo em seguida, um outro usuário do chat atualizou a imagem.

Uma outra ferramenta que eu gosto muito de usar é o [WebGraphviz](http://www.webgraphviz.com/), onde eu descrevo um grafo em `dot` e o Graphviz transforma em um SVG na tela. Daí eu uso a ferramenta de *printscreen* do próprio Firefox para usar logo em seguida aqui no site.

Por vezes, encontro um SVG na interwebs e uso o [Cloud Converter](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png), que gera um PNG e posso fazer o upload aqui mais livremente.

---

Então, quais ferramentas extra-codificação que vocês usam para ajudar na produção de conteúdo? Tem alguma configuração recomendada para a ferramenta?, Como a resolução de 150 pixels no latex2png?

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que não temos notação LaTeX?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5946/5878)

Comment: Alguém deve bater nos 10K e ter acesso à ferramentas novas até amanhã :)

Comment: @Maniero ansioso pelos 10k, mas sem muita pressa. Tenho mais pressa pela medalha de bronze em [tag:matemática], mas ainda preciso escrever mais umas 6 respostas e isso dá preguiça honesta ^^

Comment: _Habemos_ um novo **10Killer**